# Write a batch to check and return values from SQL and then run scripts determined by the return

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file, sqlcmd

Is it possible to write a batch file that will check and return a value from SQL and run a particular set of scripts depending of the return value from SQL.

For example,

If this returns a version 5 value:

```
sqlcmd -U *** -P *** -S127.0.0.1 -Q "checkversion.sql"
```

Run version 5 scripts, but ignore 1, 2, 3 and 4.

But if this returns a version 6 value:

```
sqlcmd -U *** -P *** -S127.0.0.1 -Q "checkversion.sql"
```

Run version 5 and version 6 scripts but ignore 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it all in TSQL because you can nest stored procedures